# Add Path in Android GPS

Tags: android, gps

How do I add a path betweeen several points defined by the gps in android?

Comment: Can you rephrase or clarify your question?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a [MapActivity](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html). The GPS module can be used to set several points on that Map, and with the Google Maps API, you can create a Route between those points.

Comment: yup for sure i know this i want the gps to add the points automatically not manually each place add new pointt

Comment: I'm not sure how you want to archive this. You could make something like a button which adds the current Position (Position-Data from GPS) as a point on your MapActivity. Anyways, you're going to need the LatLon of the Point you want to add.

Answer (score 0):

One thing about the maps api is that you can give it two points and it can calculate a route to this location. Using JSON you can send a request with your two points and then get a collection of points in the return JSON object.

In particular, you can take this object and decode the lat/lng of these points and then assign them accordingly and plot them on the map and then draw a line using some canvas painting. Also another thing is you can do a direct call to the Google Maps app and pass in information in the intent so that it can display the points to those particular points.

So.. in short, you have two options.